# Getting Internal Error in Android Studio Installation

Tags: software-installation, android-studio

I'm getting start failed error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath
```

Is this path variable issue?

[image]

Comment: Does upgrading your java version solve the issue?

Comment: Also, you might want to install the Oracle version of java from here - http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/oracle-java-8-stable-released-install.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Take a breath ,

1. This is not a path variable issue if it was you would not never get a screen printed with JAVA Version 1.5 or x.x 
   2.You are having an issue because of this if you see the real error which in the screenshot line which is : caused by sun.misc in gnu.gcj runtime line

So the above error can be solved by removing the gcj package and installing the any sun or oracle java because running intellij under gcj is not supported

Focus on caused by line

Comment: Can you Edit your question to include information on how you'd remove the package and install the Sun/Oracle one?